# CD-Drive removing using Java API

Tags: java, api, cd-drive

How can I close the CD-ROM tray, using Java API or JNI?

Is it possible at all to interact with cd-drive (start burning, stop, make slower or faster rotation, etc)?

Comment: do you want to open/close CD tray or want to burn disc?

Comment: It might [help you](http://java2everyone.blogspot.com/2009/03/java-open-cd-tray-in-windows-xp.html) also [try this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0574.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in Java API to do this. The next best thing which people tend to do is to dump a script specific which will open/close the CD drive. This is often done with a VBS script as @Asad Rasheed has commented.

Since you ask for a JNI way of it we will also need to know what platform you are targetting. On Windows, however, you can use [mciSendString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with something like:

```
mciSendString("set cdaudio door open", null, null, null);
```

If you want more control over **which** CD drive to open you might want to use some other function such as [DeviceIoControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

On Linux/OSX that would be

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("eject");
```